# Add a dynamic vertical and horizontal scrollbar when the contents of the canvas increases in size

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to add a vertical and horizontal scroll bar in the canvas. 
the image inside the canvas will zoom in and out like the Microsoft powerpoint slides or google maps and also need a button to get the original size of the image back.
To view the hidden area after zoom, I need the scroll bars ( not the drag with mouse down ) . How can I do this.

I tried with [Canvas Scrollbar not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385290/canvas-scrollbar-not-working) but not working exactly what I need.

Comment: This isn't a do-your-job-for-you site.  What have you tried?  Show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that adds scrollbars to accommodate oversized content.

The idea is simple:

- size a container div to your smaller desired size
- put an oversized canvas in the container div
- set overflow:scroll on the container div to get the dynamic scrollbars

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/A8u6P/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:50px; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
    div{ overflow:scroll; width:300px; height:300px; border:2px solid blue; }
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/canvas%20compositing.png";


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
            <canvas id="canvas" width=800 height=500></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @markE for your response. My canvas is of the same size as container but the contents in the canvas will zoom in/zoom out , will this work for that too. 
I am trying this code http://jsfiddle.net/ndYdk/21/

Comment: Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ndYdk/29/ In this one I am not able to scroll fully in the vertical direction.

Comment: The DOM scrollbars will activate when the content is larger than the container.  So you could make the canvas larger than the container (activating the scrollbars) and then zoom the canvas content with context.translate and context.scale.  Treat the div as a "viewport" into the canvas.

Comment: Ok.. But why the vertical scroll is not working in my fiddle. and I dont want to use translate now instead of that I need scroller.

Comment: Here's an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/VX5Up/  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks alot @markE. I figured out the problem too. Fixed it like http://jsfiddle.net/ndYdk/30/