# jQuery .on() scroll at canvas area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to detect scroll direction only when the user is at the `canvas` area.
I tried to replace `"#myCanvas"` with `"canvas"` but its not working.
Just to be sure when I change it to `documnet` its works.
How can I make it work?

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1400" height="800"></canvas>


var lastScrollTop = 0;
$("#myCanvas").on('scroll', function() {

    st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(st < lastScrollTop) {
        console.log('up 1');
    }
    else {
        console.log('down 1');
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Comment: does you canvas have a scrollbar? i think it requires to have a scrollbar for scroll event to fire http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp

Comment: I don't have scrollbar in the canvas.
is there other way I can detect the scroll direction only if the mouse is on the canvas?

Comment: see this answer for more info.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385290/canvas-scrollbar-not-working

Comment: You probably want to listen on the `wheel` event ([Get mouse wheel events in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189840/get-mouse-wheel-events-in-jquery)) that will tell you that the scroll wheel is used (or trackpad)  and not the  `scroll` event that will report if the content of an element is scrolled.

Comment: @t.niese, you right, this is what I want

Comment: So this can be marked as duplicate to the given question?

Comment: @t.niese, solved, tnx